# Subtraction of 1ms leads to unexpected behaviour

Tags: java, date, datetime

What is wrong? I assume that if I subtract 1ms from 1 Jan 1980 0:0:0 then I've got 1979. But I must subtract about 500+ ms for this. Please, give me a hint.

```
val cal = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"))
cal.set(1980, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0)
val date = new Date
date.setTime(cal.getTimeInMillis()) // <- 1980 Jan 01 0:0:0
date.setTime(cal.getTimeInMillis() - 1) // <- 1980 Jan 01 0:0:0 too !!!
```

Updated.

The solution is

```
val cal = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"))
cal.setTimeInMillis(0)
cal.set(1980, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0)
```

Comment: Just a guess, but maybe internally Calendar rounds up the seconds?

Comment: Try to print the `date` content after the first `setTime()` call. Maybe the year, month, day, hour, minute and second are the value you set, but not the millisseconds.

Comment: It is a bit confusing. I don't want use Yoda Time or another 3rd part library. I need to convert year, month, day to milliseconds and then get last millisecond of the day. I want to find correct solution for this. Unfortunately, javadoc is silent about such situation.

Comment: Even correct seconds value not sufficient for my situation. :-(

Comment: I think it's a question for Jon Skeet :-)

Comment: What syntax is that for Java? I have never seen it before.

Comment: This is Scala, but this code have no Scala specific features. Pure JVM.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With `Calendar.set(year, month, day, hourOfDay, minute, second)` no milliseconds are set. Consequently the Calendar implementation sets the milliseconds to "unknown" which is actually treated as the midpoint within the given second.

Subtracting 500ms means you just step over the midpoint. Same should happen if you add 500ms, which should bring you just over the second. Actually subtracting 500ms works and you must add 620ms to see the next second.

Comment: subtracting 500ms will not necessarily give the last millisecond of 1979.

Comment: @Ezhik, explicitely set the milliseconds with `calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);`. When you subtract one millisecond from that you directly get the last millisecond in 1979.

Comment: why add 620 specifically?